# unity3d 4.1.2 built window standalone crashed when quit application

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using unity3d 4.1.2f1,and build a window standalone version application, but when I quit the applcation, receive a application crash, but I don't get it when using 3.5.6f4. anybody know what's wrong or it's a bug of unity? I debug it using vs2010, get "CacheDownloadBuffers::~CacheDownloadBuffers memory issue". waiting for answer, thank you firstly

Comment: I was running into the same problem lately with a standalone windows build of a unity3d application with version 3.5.7f6.

Comment: when I use 3.5.6f4, it's ok. but killing process doesn't get any problem issue unitl now. enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixe it, use System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kil l() instead of Application.Quit(), and it's a bug of unity3d 4.1, They will fixe it at 4.2